# Why is my basic openGL program terminating immediately during init()?

Tags: eclipse, opengl, glut, glew

Im trying to get a basic openGL program to run. I had this code running yesterday but on a different machine and now it terminates before anything is displayed. This is my init() function:

```
void init()
{

    //generate points
    const int NumPoints = 5000;
    point3 points[NumPoints];

    point3 vertices[3] = {point3(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0),
          point3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
          point3(1.0, -1.0, 0.0)};


    points[0] = point3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    for(int k = 1; k < NumPoints; k++)
    {
        int j = rand() % 3;
        points[k] = (points[k-1]+vertices[j])/2.0;
    }

    //load shaders and use the resulting shader program
    GLuint program = InitShader("shaders/vshader.glsl", "shaders/fshader.glsl");
    glUseProgram( program );

    //create Vertex-Array object
    GLuint aBuffer;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &aBuffer);
    glBindVertexArray((GLuint)&aBuffer);

    //create Buffer object
    GLuint buffer;

    //glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points),
             points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //initialize the vertex position attribute from the vertex shader
    GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
    glVertexAttribPointer( loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  // white background

}
```

and this is my main()

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutCreateWindow("Program 1");

    glewInit();

    //do_nothing();
    init();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I figured I did some of the opengl or glut stuff wrong so I began commenting things out to pinpoint the issue. With the entire init() function commented out, I was able to display a lovely white box that didn't terminate until I clicked the X. I ended up removing all of the glFunctions within init and still had the instant termination issue. After everything, the perpetrator was this line:

```
point3 points[NumPoints];
```

Confused, I wrote do_nothing() into my main (as seen commented out above):

```
void do_nothing(){
    const int NumPoints = 5000;
    point3 points[NumPoints];
    return;
}
```

I called this instead of init() and alas, instant program termination. I don't get how something this simple could cause so much pain.

point3:

```
class point3
{
public:
    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat z;

    point3();
    point3(GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat);
    ~point3();

    point3 operator+ (point3 param);
    point3 operator- (point3 param);
    point3 operator/ (GLfloat param);
    point3 operator* (GLfloat param);
};

//
// constructiors and destructors
//

point3::point3(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
};

point3::point3(GLfloat a, GLfloat b, GLfloat c)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
    z = c;
}
```

I am using Eclipse CDT with MinGW (have to for class) on Win7

Comment: How is `point3` defined? Does it have a constructor? What does that constructor do? And since you have a whole IDE to work with, what happens when you debug into the executable?

Comment: ive never worked with an IDE before this class. Ive always just used vim on a linux machine dgb for debugging. `point3` is in a seperate file. Ill add it right now

Comment: oh man sorry to sound so excited but this debugger is just a pretty gdb with more specific and intuitive commands! I dig it!

Comment: still cant figure out the issue though

Comment: The fact that you can just comment out init, and still have a "lovely white box", implies that there's some initialization code somewhere else.

In either case, tell us what the debugger actually pointed out; typically, when you have a segfault, gdb will tell you the problematic line.

Comment: The white box was from all the glutInit* functions. init() just initialized my data to be drawn, buffers, and shaders. The issue ended up being due to calling glutDisplayFunc(display) before the call to glewInit().